# Is there an accepted format for comedy sketch writing?

Tags: screenwriting

I have been doing Google searches for examples or teleplays to download that may offer insight for sketch comedy writing.  Is there a specific format that those in the industry follow or is simply the same teleplay/screenplay format used by the rest of the industry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell from some brief research, it is the same format as when writing a script for radio, or television. For example, from this article regarding [Comedy Sketch Writing](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/2008/sep/22/comedy2) (written by Richard Herring, David Mitchell and Robert Webb):

> I started my professional career
>   writing topical sketches for the now
>   defunct Radio 4 show Weekending. I
>   actually pretty much loathed the
>   programme, as it was rather formulaic
>   and rarely biting. Yet I stayed for a
>   year, serving an apprenticeship that
>   **taught me many skills: from the
>   mundane business of how to format a
>   script** (for this and further advice
>   see [bbc.co.uk/writersroom](http://www.bbc.co.uk/writersroom)) to
>   technical tricks such as how to avoid
>   clunky exposition

Emphasis mine.

I recommend having a look at the [BBC Script Archive](http://www.bbc.co.uk/writersroom/scripts) for examples of sketch comedy scripts for TV and radio.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think about checking out BBC content!